# C# WPF позиция ContextMenu не отвечает выбраному ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть ListView с ListViewItem элементами. В стиль ListViewItem ControlTemplate.Triggers добавил

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
  <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=ContextMenu.IsOpen}" Value="True"/>
    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
  </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Цель проста, засветить ListViewItem когда открыто ContextMenu. Все вро

де работает но если рандомно кликать ПКМ то иногда ContextMenu стоит на другом ListViewItem чем выбранный судя по цвету и кстати если забиндить команду к ListViewItem из ContextMenu то она работает с ListViewItem который под ContextMenu а не с красным, почему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private void ListViewItem_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
  ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)sender;
  item.IsSelected = true;
  item.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = item;
  item.ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.MousePoint;
  item.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
  e.Handled = true; 
}
```

Comment: Насколько я помню, контекстное меню появляется там, и для того элемента, где правая кнопка мыши была отпущена, а красный цвет у вас - там, где была нажата (или наоборот). Думаю, вы уже догадались, как синхронизировать.

Comment: Как это воспроизвести? Покажите разметку контрола целиком.

Comment: @aepot вроде синхронизовал, добавил код, но только в XAML не сделать такое наверное

Comment: Черт, я UI на C# не понимаю. :(

Comment: @aepot, лень на github) https://fex.net/s/nyeooeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется победил.

Вот такая разметка

```xml
<ListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <local:ContextMenuTargetConverter x:Key="ContextMenuTargetConverter"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding PlacementTarget.Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="1" Padding="3">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ContextMenu.IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Value="True">
                            <Condition.Binding>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ContextMenuTargetConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="ContextMenu.PlacementTarget" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Condition.Binding>
                        </Condition>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListViewItem Content="1"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="2"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="3"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="4"/>
</ListView>
```

И вот такой конвертер

```cs
public class ContextMenuTargetConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
        => values?.Length > 1 && values[0] == values[1];

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => null!;
}
```

Делаю то же самое, что и вы, при этих же действиях проблема больше не воспроизводится.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не советую использовать красный цвет для тестов, wpf в случае ошибки ui красит в красный любой объект, это легко воспроизвести для примера.

Comment: @xellan это просто пример

Comment: это я понял, но автору на заметку будет. Хотя сейчас дату ответа посмотрел, он наверное это уже знает)